# Одинаковые байты, разные представления

Tags: c++, строки

Могут ли существовать две строки `std::string a` и `std::string b`, для которых `a == b` возвращает `true`, но они имеют разный вид при `std::cout << a << b`?

Comment: если два обьекта имеют разные значения, они не могут быть равны, если только  эти обьекты не пользовательского типа, для которого оператор  == определен иначе

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я про представление на экране спрашиваю, оно может быть разным?

Comment: Уважаемый  stat, я вас не очень понимаю, поскольку  на экран (консоль или любой другой поток) выводится значение. Если вы имеете ввиду размер или форму шрифта, то это не имеет значение...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan значение - это байт(ы), а представление - картинка

Comment: Не могут, откуда вопрос?

Comment: @ixSci даже если строки в разных кодировках?

Comment: `std::string` это не строка, это набор `char`ов. В C++ нет строк, поэтому разные кодировки не дадут `true` при сравнении.

Comment: @ixSci да, я понимаю, но эти charы, т.е. байты, в одной кодировке представляют одно, а в другой - другое. может ли быть такое что байты совпадают в разных кодировках, а представления - нет?

Comment: @ixSci или вы имеете в виду, что `std::string` никак не связан с кодировкой, поэтому сравниваться байты будут всегда в 1?

Comment: Нет, представление выбирается на основании чисел (значения байтов). Т.е. к примеру, в кодировке А значение 35 будет выводить оленя, а в Б — тюленя. Но это будет одно значение — 35. Чтобы вывело и оленя и тюленя придётся менять представление (кодировку вывода), а она одна на всю консоль, а не построчная.

Comment: @ixSci понял, это кодировка вывода от ос зависит и в рантайме нельзя поменять?

Comment: @ixSci то есть могу ли я вывести сначала `a`, потом поменять кодировку и вывести другое `b`?

Comment: @stat, я не уверен, что существуют консоли, в которых можно менять codepage для части вывода. Чисто теоретически, Вы можете такую написать, только в чём смысл? Всё равно руками менять придётся.

Comment: @ixSci понял, большое спасибо, вообще вопрос возник в связи с тем, нужно ли добавлять свою hash и equal в unordered контейнер с ключом std::string , строки могут быть в разных кодировках и разных языках. получается не надо

Comment: Просто на будущее: Вы лучше в вопросе сразу реальную проблему указывайте, так будет легче понять друг друга.

Comment: могут, тут есть примеры когда https://arne-mertz.de/2018/09/when-different-values-compare-equal/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не могут, т.к. `operator<<` для строки [обязан учитывать](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.view.io) всю строку (begin, end), так же как `operator==` [учитывает всю строку](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.compare) через `data()` & `size()`, т.е. никаких хитрых трюков с добавлением куда-нибудь `\0` не выйдет. А в остальном, `std::string` это набор `char`ов, а если один набор `char`ов идентичен другому, значит и на устройство вывода оба набора будут выведены одинаково.